# Adding Strava WMTS to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wmts, strava

I'd like to add some Strava WMTS to ArcGIS.

The QuickMapServices QGIS plugin can achieve this.

[image]

The layer details of this plugin show [this information](https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/495/) with the following:

- URL: http://globalheat.strava.com/tiles/cycling/color1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- Z min: None
- Z max: None
- Y origin top: True

Is there any way to use the information given to add this service in ArcMap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the ArcGIS QMS plugin (ArcQMS). 
See https://my.nextgis.com/downloads/software/arcqms/ArcQMSInstaller.msi

More information see here:

- https://qms.nextgis.com/about
- http://nextgis.com/blog/qms-service/

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have finally tried this and it works really well. Now, the problem is that we don't have the privileges to install the .msi, and the process of getting it done it's a bit tedious, specially since we are many potential users. So, your answer is valid and I'll assign you the bounty unless there is another answer to achieve this in a way we can easily implement it manually or via Add-in Manager.

Comment: Btw, great work by NextGIS!!

Comment: I can't resize the window or select the metadata, so I cannot access the websites with the terms, copyright, description... Are you aware of this issue?

Comment: You can create issue here https://github.com/nextgis/ArcQMS/issues